# Haskell ::Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'

Tags: string, haskell, functional-programming

I want a program that takes lines and prints reverse when it encounters an empty line.
This is my code.

```
back :: IO()
back = do
  line <- getLine 
  if (not $ null line) then do
  mapM_ putStrLn (reverse line)
  else return()
```

When I try to run this it gives an error.

```
* Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'
      Expected: [String]
        Actual: [Char]
    * In the second argument of `mapM_', namely `(reverse line)'
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: mapM_ putStrLn (reverse line)
      In the expression: do mapM_ putStrLn (reverse line)
  |
6 |     mapM_ putStrLn(reverse line)
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

`line` is a `String`. Since you use `mapM_ putStrLn`, it expects a list of strings, so `mapM_ putStrLn :: [String] -> IO ()`.

It is not entirely clear if you want to reverse each line, or the lines itself. In case of the former, you can work with:

```
back :: IO()
back = do
  line <- getLine 
  if not (null line) then do
    putStrLn (reverse line)
    back
  else return()
```

in case of the latter, you can use recursion, and first call `back` recursively, and *then* print the line:

```
back :: IO()
back = do
  line <- getLine 
  if not (null line) then do
    back
    putStrLn line
  else return()
```